# Knife SSL check fails when workstation is undocked

Tags: ssl, chef-infra, knife

My Chef workstation is a virtual machine. I initially setup this machine with Hosted Chef server while the machine was docked in my computer's dock and hardlined to the internet.

When I undock the workstation, the knife ssl command fails with the following error:

```
c2-device@c2failover-VirtualBox:~$ cd chef/
c2-device@c2failover-VirtualBox:~/chef$ knife ssl check
Connecting to host api.chef.io:443
ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings
c2-device@c2failover-VirtualBox:~/chef$
```

I have since assigned a resolvable IP address to the VM workstation as it was using DHCP prior. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue or what the issue may be when undocking my workstation. Does anyone have any possible causes or solutions to the issue I'm seeing?

my network interface is configured as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address XXX.XXX.X.XXX
        netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.X
        gateway XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
        dns-nameservers X.X.X.X
```

I have not been able to find much in the chef documentation about this issue. Thanks for any help in advance, I'm fairly new to Chef.

Comment: This is not an SO question, but my first guess would be this is due to using different networks when docked vs. undocked (e.g. wired when docked vs. wireless when undocked), and some difference between them is causing your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your assessment of the issue. I'm wondering are there any specific steps you can think of taking in order to root out what the issue here may be? Perhaps there is some logging that can be enabled or a network setting I can check that would be indicative of the issue here? Verifying the SSL connection with Hosted Chef server is the failing action, so possibly it is related to a network property used specifically by SSL?

Comment: "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known" is a general error indicating that DNS lookup failed. It can't resolve the host name of your chef server.

Comment: Hmm that's good information. It is a hosted chef server. Do you know what information (or how to get that information), would be passed from my Chef workstation machine in performing the DNS lookup? I have run the ifconfig command in terminal on the workstation both when docked and undocked with identical results yielded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Chef or knife. You'll need to ensure the VM is able to reach the Internet in general. Overall we do not recommend using a VM as your workstation, you the actual desktop or laptop that you work on.

Comment: Awesome thank you for your input coderanger. I was hoping to see you here :) I can access the internet using a browser, however I do still see this error. I believe your correct that this is not related to Chef or Knife. 
I'm working on getting a machine with linux as the native OS up and running as my chef workstation. Are you fairly confident that this should resolve the issue I'm seeing with the VM workstation setup (i.e. this particular issue)?

Comment: Can you use a browser from your laptop or from the VM itself? I would try something like "curl google.com" from inside the VM.

Comment: Yes, I can browse the web using a web browser when this machine is undocked. The issue doesn't appear to be with network connectivity to the internet, but with some network configuration change that causes the SSL verification between workstation and server to fail. Something to note is that when I undock the machine, my VM undergoes some kind of network configuration task before booting the VM (which it does not if docked).

Comment: I'm wondering if this tidbit I found on Virtualbox's site has anything to do with this issue: "Bridging to a wireless interface is done differently from bridging to a wired interface, because most wireless adapters do not support promiscuous mode. All traffic has to use the MAC address of the host's wireless adapter, and therefore VirtualBox needs to replace the source MAC address in the Ethernet header of an outgoing packet to make sure the reply will be sent to the host interface."